# Python Print Function City name

Tags: python, list, dictionary, printing

I'm trying to print 'Phoenix' from this list dictionary but can't extract the specific name.

```
test = [{'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu'}, 1000, 2000, 3000, ['hat', 't-shirt', 'jeans', {'socks1': 'red', 'socks2': 'blue'}]]
```

`print(test[0])` gives me all the city names... How do I display just 'Phoenix'?

Comment: try doing `print(test[0]['Arizona'])`

Comment: If any of the replies below helped you, consider accepting them by clicking the check mark. Please note that there is no obligation to do so!

Answer (score 2):

With `test[0]` you're just accessing the first element of the list test, which in this case is the dictionary.

You need to use the key - in this case *Arizona*:

```
print(test[0]['Arizona'])
```

Output is `Phoenix`.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up a bit on the dictionary data structure. But here you go:

```
test[0]['Arizona']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the below code snippet and you will get your answer by your own most probably.

```
test = [{'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu'}, 1000, 2000, 3000,
        ['hat', 't-shirt', 'jeans', {'socks1': 'red', 'socks2': 'blue'}]]

print(test[0]['Arizona'])

for index in range(len(test)):
    print("test[" + str(index) + "]:")
    print(str(test[index]))
    print()
```

The output will be like the below:

```
Phoenix
test[0]:
{'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu'}

test[1]:
1000

test[2]:
2000

test[3]:
3000

test[4]:
['hat', 't-shirt', 'jeans', {'socks1': 'red', 'socks2': 'blue'}]
```

The output explains that test is an array of 5 elements and the 0th element is an associative array. Thus, to output Phoenix, you have to use test[0]['Arizona']

Answer (score 0):

If you use just `test[0]`, you can just access the first element in the `test` list:
`{'Arizona': 'Phoenix', 'California': 'Sacramento', 'Hawaii': 'Honolulu'}`.

The `test[0]` is a dictionary. And you need to get 'Phoenix' which is the value of the key 'Arizona', you can just use the key to get the value:
`test[0]['Arizona']`